# Is it possible to import users into CRM 2011 and specify which Business Unit they should be in?

Tags: dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm, crm

I've got a file which I'm trying to import to the User entity.

When I get the list of fields to map to, Business Unit (Lookup) isn't one of them.

This is a required field in the User window so how do I set this. If it automatically takes the top level business unit, what is the recommended way to cycle through them updating them?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, figured out the best way to do it is via the SDK - Business Unit can be set there without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

After users import they will have top level Business Unit set. You already have option *Change Business Unit* in CRM.

[image: change users bu]

Just one note, you can change BU only to Enabled users. So after import, first enable all users, because they are in disabled state.

Hope that helps.